# Aptana Studio 3 - strange characters showing up in HTML code

Tags: php, html, aptana3

I am running into a problem and I'm wondering if anyone else has come across it. I am working on some PHP pages in Aptana Studio 3. They were created by another web developer. When I open the PHP files in Aptana the apostrophes (') and quotes (" ") in the paragraph text are showing up as a white question mark in a black diamond shape: �

Any ideas on what could be causing this? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Check your encoding, it may be encoded in a different text format. Try UTF8 encoding with/without BOM.

Comment: David, I checked the encoding option under Workspace and it looks like it's set for UTF8 as you recommended. I did discover that the file was set to ISO-8859-1 encoding. I have set aptana for that, hopefully it will solve the problem. Thanks very much for the help David!

Comment: No problem, I just posted an answer to this question if you wanted to accept it. Hopefully this may help somebody else when they're searching around. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually these symbols are indicative of an encoding issue. UTF-8 is pretty much standard. Verify that you have the proper encoding across all your environments.

This may be a good resource for you: [PHP: The Right Way - Working with UTF-8](http://www.phptherightway.com/#php_and_utf8)